# Gradle sonarqube plugin - how to set memory for findbugs?

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, gradle-plugin

I have a project module with 30K classes.
After migrating sonar analysis from ant script to gradle plugin I have OOM error with output like this:

> 13:10:36 Out of memory
> 13:10:36 Total memory: 954M
> 13:10:36  free memory: 119M
>
> 13:10:52 Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
> 13:10:52  at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutor.execute(FindbugsExecutor.java:163)
> 13:10:52  ... 109 more
> 13:10:52 Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
> 13:10:52  at

We've run ant script with the following parameters "-Xmx3800m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m"

**How can I set the same parameters for sonarqube gradle plugin?**

I've tried setting the following env variable before calling gradle

> GRADLE_OPTS=-Xmx3800m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m

It's applied correctly, but findbugs still failing and prints "Total memory: 954M"

Also I've tried adding the following properties to reduce memory consumption, but without any luck

```
property 'sonar.skipPackageDesign', 'true'
property 'sonar.skipDesign', 'true'
```

Gradle version is 3.5
Sonarqube plugin version is 2.5
jdk version is 8u131

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized what was the problem.
Setting GRADLE_OPTS was correct solution, however I also used gradle daemon, so those options were ignored for daemon.
I ended up disabling daemon by adding -Dorg.gradle.daemon=false to GRADLE_OPTS and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Check build.gradle file and set maxHeapSize as given below,

```
 tasks.withType(FindBugs) {
            maxHeapSize = "1000m"
        }
```

You can change heap size.

Comment: This allows to set heap size when using Findbugs gradle plugin. But I have different case - it's sonar gradle plugin that uses FindBugs sonar sensor.